# String format 1 as 01 in Apex to build a drop down menu

Tags: apex

I have a drop down whose select options are been constructed from Apex. Currently the option is showing as `1` whereas i want it as `01` and so on for 1 digit Integer in the drop down menu.

Below is the Apex code that constructs the Select Option.

```
public List<SelectOption> getExiprationMonth() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    options.add(new SelectOption('', ''));
    for(Integer i=1;i<=12;i++) {
        options.add(new SelectOption(String.valueOf(i), String.valueOf(i)));
    }
    return options;
}
```

> I don't want to have extra if else conditions instead i am searching
>   the right formating option if any.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@RCS - Easiest way to to it:

```
public List<SelectOption> getExiprationMonth() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    options.add(new SelectOption('', ''));
    for(Integer i=1;i<=12;i++) {
        options.add(new SelectOption(String.valueOf(i), String.valueOf('0' + i).right(2)));
    }
    return options;
}
```

Note: I added this to the label portion: `String.valueOf('0' + i).right(2)` which essentially prepends a 0 to the number and takes the right 2 characters. So if the integer is 2 or more character in length it will not have the added 0.

Simply copy to the value part of your selectOptions if you need the value to have the 0 as well

Comment: @RCS - My pleasure

Comment: Hey @Eric just a thought can we use String.leftpad as well or what?

Comment: @RCS - Only if you want spaces instead of 0

Comment: ohh i thought we can specify "0" instead of space my bad

Answer (score 0):

Just change the for loop and check if the below code works:

```
if(i<10)
    options.add(new SelectOption(0+''+String.valueOf(i),0+''+String.valueOf(i)));
else
    options.add(new SelectOption(String.valueOf(i), String.valueOf(i)));
```

Comment: I don't want to have extra conditions instead i am searching the right formating option.

Comment: Can't think of any such formatting options.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(Integer i=1;i<=12;i++) {
  if(i <= 9) {
    options.add(new SelectOption(String.valueOf(i), '0'+String.valueOf(i)));
  }
  else {
    options.add(new SelectOption(String.valueOf(i), String.valueOf(i)));
  }
}
```

It will show to users as 01, 02,...and so on.

Comment: I don't want to have extra conditions instead i am searching the right formating option.

Comment: right now one thing is coming in my mind is that, u can define a Set or List of String with values 01,02,... . Then you don't need to use if else, u can simply access the list or set by its index

Answer (score 0):

this is another way:

```
public List<SelectOption> getExiprationMonth() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('', ''));
        for(Integer i=1;i<=12;i++) {
            options.add(new SelectOption(String.valueOf(i), String.valueOf(i).leftPad(2,'0')));
        }
        return options;
    }
```